# How to show a decimal value as a currency value on front-end using Angular?

Tags: entity-framework-core, angular10, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a requirement to display the values of textbox fields as -

Ex: **$1,234,500.06** but the value that I get from the back-end i.e. .NET core API and Entity Framework core is 1234500.06

So, was wondering if it's possible to include comma separators and $ as a prefix in UI ( I am using Angular 10).

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use pipe number format for show commas and decimal point. Add the currency symbol manually. I'm not sure if there are some way to get this

```
<label> $ {{price | number: '1.0-3':'en-US'}} </label>
```